# Problem when run onpress fonction : react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, onpress

I would just like to be redirected to my "Profile" page when I click on the "Enter" button. I don't know if this is the correct method but my homepage is App.js and it contains my button and my image. Sorry for the mistakes I am a beginner and moreover French!

app.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import DisplayAnImage from './Components/DisplayAnImage';
import Profile from './Components/Profile';
import { Enter } from './Components/Enter';
import { StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';




export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <DisplayAnImage/>
        <Enter/>
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}
```

enter.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button, Alert, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import Profile from './Profile.js';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { StackNavigator } from  'react-navigation';




export const Enter = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.Button}>
      <View>
        <Button
          title="Entrer"
          color="#FFFFFF"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}





const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Button: {
    flex: 1,
    marginHorizontal: 120,
    borderRadius: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#1067b3'
    },
  title: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginVertical: 8,
  },
  fixToText: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  separator: {
    marginVertical: 8,
    borderBottomColor: '#737373',
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
  },
});
```

profile.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';


export default class Profile extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Profile</Text>
            </View>
            );
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You have not setup the navigation, better go through https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You are calling "this" from your functional component. Please change this

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}
```

to

```
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
```

Comment: Hello thank you very much, I've got this error now :
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
...